# javascript embed being strange

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to embed a bandsintown "marquee" banner in my band site, the javascript is loading fine but the text is being cut in half horizontally… I've traced it to the foundation.css file as it works fine when I don't use that stylesheet. I was just wondering if anyone could point me to where I could look in the foundation css file for anything that might be affecting the script…

Any help would be much appreciated! Its so annoying as it should work fine!

This is the code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bandsintown.com/javascripts/bit_marquee_widget.js'></script><a href="http://www.bandsintown.com/jouis" class="bit-marquee-initializer" data-artist="jouis">Bandsintown</a>
```

If you put it in a blank html without then with the latest zurb foundation css you'll see what I mean.

Thanks in advance

Louis

Comment: Why not use `Firebug` for `Firefox`, or `Chrome Developer tools` to inspect the `CSS`, and see what's causing the issue?

Comment: doh! thanks Nick R, will check it now

Comment: Yeh the console should let you know if there are any errors in the Javascript and which line they are on. See here for more: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: Sorted! For reference it was this: *, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}  in foundation.css, deleted it and it works! yes! let's hope it doesn't mess anything else up though, so far so good. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!